# OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android NDK: Nothing being drawn

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I have a 2D game project that I'm porting to Android that utilizes OpenGL ES 2.0. I am having trouble getting anything drawn on the screen (except for a solid color from clearing the screen). Everything renders just fine when running in my Windows environment, but of course the environment is set up differently for the different version of OpenGL.

I followed the native-activity sample and took advice from several other OpenGL ES 2.0 resources to compose what I currently have.

I have checked everything I know how to with no anomalous results. As mentioned, `glClear` works, and displays the color set by `glClearColor`. I also know that every frame is being rendered, as changing glClearColor frame-by-frame displays the different colors. Of course, the application properly compiles. My textures are loaded from the proper location in the app's cache. `glGetError` is returning `GL_NO_ERROR` at every step in the process, so what I am doing appears to be accepted by OpenGL. My shaders are loaded without error. I have also tested this on both a few emulators and my physical android device, so it isn't localized to a specific device configuration.

I speculate that it must be some mistake in how I initialize and set up OpenGL. I am hoping someone more versed in OpenGL ES than I am will be able to help root out my problem. I am pasting the different relevant sections of my code below. `engine` is a global struct I am presently using out of laziness.

**Initializing the display**

```
static int AND_InitDisplay() {

    // Desired display attributes
    const EGLint attribs[] = {
            EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
            EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
            EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
            EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
            EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
            EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
            EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
            EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLint w, h, dummy, format;
    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLSurface surface;
    EGLContext context;

    EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    eglInitialize(display, 0, 0);
    eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs);
    eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(engine->app->window, 0, 0, format);

    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, engine->app->window, NULL);

    EGLint const attrib_list[3] = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE};
    context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, attrib_list);

    if (eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context) == EGL_FALSE) {
        LOGW("Unable to eglMakeCurrent");
        return -1;
    }

    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);
    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);

    engine->display = display;
    engine->context = context;
    engine->surface = surface;
    engine->width = w;
    engine->height = h;

    // Initialize GL state.
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    return 0;
}
```

**Drawing a frame**

```
static void AND_drawFrame() {
    if (engine->display == NULL) {
        LOGW("DB E: DISPLAY IS NULL");
        // No display.
        return;
    }

    // Clearing with red color. This displays properly.
    glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // eglSwapBuffers results in no visible change
    eglSwapBuffers(engine->display, engine->surface);
}
```

**Example of preparing VBO data**

I understand many wouldn't like the idea of using multiple VBOs for the same geometry. I would love to hear if this code isn't orthodox or is incorrect, but I am not focused on this unless it the root of my problem.

```
GLfloat charPosVerts[] = {

    p0.x, p0.y, 0.f,
    p1.x, p0.y, 0.f,
    p1.x, p1.y, 0.f,

    p0.x, p0.y, 0.f,
    p1.x, p1.y, 0.f,
    p0.x, p1.y, 0.f
};

GLfloat charTexVerts[] = {
    0.0, 0.0,
    textures[texid].w, 0.0,
    textures[texid].w, textures[texid].h,

    0.0, 0.0,
    textures[texid].w, textures[texid].h,
    0.0, textures[texid].h
};

GLfloat charColorVerts[] = {
    e->color.r, e->color.g, e->color.b, e->color.a,
    e->color.r, e->color.g, e->color.b, e->color.a,
    e->color.r, e->color.g, e->color.b, e->color.a,

    e->color.r, e->color.g, e->color.b, e->color.a,
    e->color.r, e->color.g, e->color.b, e->color.a,
    e->color.r, e->color.g, e->color.b, e->color.a
};

glGenBuffers(1, &(e->vboPos));
glGenBuffers(1, &(e->vboTex));
glGenBuffers(1, &(e->vboColor));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, e->vboPos);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(charPosVerts), charPosVerts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderIDs.attribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderIDs.attribPosition);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, e->vboTex);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(charTexVerts), charTexVerts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderIDs.attribTexCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderIDs.attribTexCoord);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, e->vboColor);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(charColorVerts), charColorVerts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderIDs.attribColors, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderIDs.attribColors);
```

**Example of drawing VBO**

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, CORE_GetBmpOpenGLTex(texix));
glUniform1i(shaderIDs.uniTexture, 0);

// Draw the sprite
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, e->vboPos);
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderIDs.attribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderIDs.attribPosition);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, e->vboTex);
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderIDs.attribTexCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderIDs.attribTexCoord);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, e->vboColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderIDs.attribColors, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderIDs.attribColors);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18);
```

**Vertex Shader**

The shaders are very simple.

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
attribute vec4 colors;

varying vec2 texCoordVar;
varying vec4 colorsVar;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoordVar = texCoord;
    colorsVar = colors;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

varying vec2 texCoordVar;
varying vec4 colorsVar;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texCoordVar) * colorsVar;
}
```

Thanks for looking at this long post. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do your shaders compile without errors? I always thought OpenGL ES 2.0 requires adding precision for floats in fragment shaders but I might be mistaken.

Comment: @harism That's correct. Also, in the posted code, `AND_drawFrame()` is not actually drawing anything.

Comment: I am triple checking the shader compilation now. @Reto Koradi I guess the function name is misnomer. You're right, it is only doing the swap. Unless I misunderstand you and there is something else I should be doing.

Comment: It's clearing the window, and then doing the swap, without anything in between. If you want to render something, you'll have to do that between the `glClear()` call and the `eglSwapBuffers()` call.

Comment: Wow, what a rookie mistake. That was obviously the problem. Thanks a lot for saving the day, Reto. You might want to add that as an answer to the problem.

Comment: Not sure if it will have much general value, but I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code is not drawing anything. From the `AND_drawFrame()` function:

```
// Clearing with red color. This displays properly.
glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// eglSwapBuffers results in no visible change
eglSwapBuffers(engine->display, engine->surface);
```

Based on this, the draw code is either never invoked, or the window is cleared **after** drawing, which would wipe out everything that was drawn before.